# Spring boot Jar Authentication exception

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy  spring boot application  jar , the application is running and i tried
`http://localhost:8080` in my browser , But it is showing a dialog box to enter authentication details like username and password .

Please help me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you see a password logged at INFO on startup? The username is "user".

Comment: i have seen this-    Using default security password:abc2134d-3456-4e12-ba19-ca4efa08f5d2      , is this the one you are asking?

Comment: That sounds like it fits the bill. Did you try it?

Comment: no again invalid username/ password .    username : user(lowerquotes) passsword: what i told to you previously

Comment: It is showing only greetings from spring. but it is showing default index.jsp . but it is not loading my view class

Comment: Then that's a new question?

Comment: yes. it is not reading the package where my controllers are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see a password logged at INFO on startup? The username is "user". Docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security).

Comment: how to change the default password? .In the documentation i found  "security.user.password" can be used . But where i can do this operation?

Comment: Maybe you need to read a bit more of that user guide? Spring Boot looks for an application.properties file in the root of the classpath (among other locations).